# Chart with left-right highlight

Tags: c#, charts, limits

I want to make chart in C# with limit highlight like on screen below

[image]

Does someone know some library to make something like this?

Comment: Many commercial libraries offer this, DevExpress for one. OR did you mean for free?

Comment: Microsoft Chart Controls http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart, remember that it's always hard to create charts like this no matter which library you chose.

Comment: You can use a MSChart and draw the rectangle in the PrePaint event.